# What does the notation "kg kg-1" for units mean for specific humidity

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, humidity

I am using a data set from Justin Sheffield at Princeton that includes specific humidity. The description is as follows:

> "Reanalysis 6-hourly specific humidity interpolated to 1.0deg with account for elevation changes and scaled to maintain consistency with reanalysis relative humidity and CRU TS3.0 monthly air temperature";
>   The units are = "kg kg-1"

What does this mean? Does it mean kg/kg so essentially dimensionless? Because I have seen around specific humidity measured also in g/kg, maybe that was wrong? 
These two pages give the same definition of specific and absolute humidity, I thought they were different things: 
http://www.nzifst.org.nz/unitoperations/drying3.htm
http://tigge.ecmwf.int/tigge/d/show_object/table=parameters/name=specific_humidity/levtype=pl/

Comment: Humidity is generally expressed as a ratio, which is dimensionless. E.g $kg/kg$ as in your example.

Comment: $1\,{\rm g}/{\rm kg} = 0.001$. Yes, that's technically a valid (dimensionless) unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to expand on yo's answer:

It's unit-less so, mathematically, you could omit the kg/kg. However then the reader wouldn't know if you're expressing a quantity as a percent weight or a percent volume which are different.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the unit is kilogram per kilogram, but it means kilogram of water (moisture) per kilogram of air.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is that by mentioning $\mathrm{kg}\, \mathrm{kg}^{-1}$ you make it clear that you measure the weight. You can think of it as

$$ 0.01\, \mathrm{kg}\, \mathrm{kg}^{-1} = 1\, \mathrm{wt.}\%. $$

This is to avoid confusion with $\mathrm{vol.}\,\%$.

Comment: *kg* is mass, *N* would be weight, right?